# How to use an external Javascript library with a Vue.js cli project?

Tags: webpack, vuejs2

I recently made my first Vue.js project with Vue CLI.
I want to import [SVG.js](https://svgjs.com) so I installed it with

```
npm install @svgdotjs/svg.js
```

My `/src/components/Map.vue` file:

```
<template>
  <div id="drawing"></div> 
</template>

<script>
  import SVG from '@svgdotjs/svg.js';
  export default {
    name: 'Map'
  }      
  let draw = SVG('drawing').size(300, 300) // TypeError
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

The browser complains when I use the SVG function with the error:

```
Map.vue?108f:10 Uncaught TypeError: _svgdotjs_svg_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default(...) is not a function
    at eval (Map.vue?108f:10)
    at Module../node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/components/Map.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (app.js:954)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:724)
    at fn (app.js:101)
    at eval (Map.vue?d6e9:1)
    at Module../src/components/Map.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (app.js:2526)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:724)
    at fn (app.js:101)
    at eval (Map.vue?9397:1)
    at Module../src/components/Map.vue (app.js:2514)
```

How should I use or import the SVG library with Vue.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use SVG in the `export default {}` block.

---

For example

```
export default {
  mounted() {
    let draw = SVG("drawing").size(300, 300);
  }
};
```

Comment: Then I got this: 
`[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: _svgdotjs_svg_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default(...) is not a function"
`

Comment: Did you use Vue CLI 3 ?

Comment: Yes, I created the project in January 2019 using [Vue UI](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html#using-the-gui)

Comment: I don't quite sure why `npm install @svgdotjs/svg.js` can't work. However, i found you can `npm install svg.js` and then `import SVG from 'svg.js'`. That should be work.